# Dynamically moving a control for each character in a Textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Basically I'm trying to make a CheckBox move to the right using:

```
 chk_ShowPassword.Location = New Point(X, Y)
```

Now the way I'm trying to do this is by checking for each character in the textbox and depending on the amount of characters there is, the checkbox will move to the right. I'm using:

```
For Each chr As Char In tb1.Text
        chk_ShowPassword.Location = New Point(++85, 95)
Next
```

I need help with 2 things, I'm not sure why but it seems to be not moving to the right. It's meant to be moving to the right by 85 for each character. The other thing is that is 85 a good increment method for each character, is it too much, too little,

Can someone help me with this. Please if it's not clear you can ask me where to expand on and I'll do my best.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by ,is 85 too much or to little ? if you type to much it will go of the screen :). so depends what you trying to do.

Comment: @Creator the 85 was just an example. I did 85 because doing something too little like say 45 or 35 would overlap with the text in the textbox, 85 seems like an appropriate amount because I feel like there is a good amount of gap between the text and the control i.e. the control being a CheckBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its important to save the starting point and do the movements from there. "Orgchk_ShowPasswordLocation"
So you can always go back to the starting point.
Do a count for the chars and then use "Orgchk_ShowPasswordLocation.X + Count * 10"
Then it will move forward or backwards if you add or delete chars in the text box.

```
Dim Orgchk_ShowPasswordLocation As Point
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Orgchk_ShowPasswordLocation = chk_ShowPassword.Location
End Sub

Dim cby As Integer
Dim cbx As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tb1.TextChanged
    cby = chk_ShowPassword.Location.Y
    cbx = chk_ShowPassword.Location.X
    Count = Nothing

    For Each chr As Char In tb1.Text

        Count = Count + 1
    Next
    cbx = Orgchk_ShowPasswordLocation.X + Count * 10
    chk_ShowPassword.Location = New Point(cbx, cby)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. It works the way I want it to and I'll work my way to modifying it.

Comment: i have made some improvements just check it :). mybe its saves you some time.